# Excel formula - min, max

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

x=...

y=...

5*(x-y)=

if "x" and "y" are with different signs (-/+ or +/-) the formula should be like that,

but if "x" and "y" are with same signs (-/- or +/+) in the brackets should stay only one value with his sign - the absolute value of (x and y).

How should it look like?

Comment: "the formula should be like that," - which formula? What have you tried to solve it? What was exactly the issue? Please post sample data with desired results to help us understanding your problem.

Comment: If we have different signs:
x=1
y=-2
The formula should look like this: 5*(1-(-2))

If we have similar signs:
x=-3
y=-6
The formula should look like this: 5*(0-(-6))

One more example:
x=-3
y=-1
->   5*(-3-0)

Comment: "x=-3 y=-6 The formula should look like this: 5*(0-(-6))" - changing from `-3` to `0`?? "x=-3 y=-1 -> 5*(-3-0)" - again -1 to 0?? Please don't answer in comments, but edit your question, also please take care to post it correctly. Also what do you mean by "absolute value of (x and y)"? Maximum of absolute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use this formula:

`=5*IF(SIGN(A2)=SIGN(B2),IF(SIGN(A2)=1,MAX(A2,B2),MIN(A2,B2)),A2-B2)`

How it works:

- `IF(SIGN(A2)=SIGN(B2)` - if signs are the same

  - `IF(SIGN(A2)=1` - if numbers are positive
  - `MAX(A2,B2)` - returns bigger number
  - `MIN(A2,B2)` - returns smaller number (bigger absolute value for negative numbers mean smaller number)
- else returns `A2-B2`

[image]

Comment: That's what I meant! Thank you very much! You make my life easier!